# New Anaconda3 installation, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

This is a FRESH installation of Anaconda, so the issues with updating python don't apply here. Uninstalling and reinstalling causes the same errors.

Upon starting up the Anaconda prompt I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\AnacondaInstallation\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'

C:\Users\xianx>where conda
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

I manually added these three lines to my Path variable, but I'm still getting that error upon opening up the Anaconda prompt.
`D:\AnacondaInstallation\Scripts`,
`D:\AnacondaInstallation`,
`D:\AnacondaInstallation\Library\bin`

I also see it when I try to install any sort of package. The system seems to recognize the conda command enough to run `conda-script.py`.

```
D:\AnacondaInstallation\Scripts>conda install pytorch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\AnacondaInstallation\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'

D:\AnacondaInstallation\Scripts>where conda
D:\AnacondaInstallation\Scripts\conda.exe
D:\AnacondaInstallation\Library\bin\conda.bat
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I had multiple Python installations all over the place. Once I cleaned those out of my PATH environment variable and put in the Anaconda ones, the issue resolved itself.